# How to add multiple draggable “textfield” to add text over images in flutter?

Tags: image, flutter, text, stack, draggable

I am making meme generator app . And i need to show multiple texts over the images , I am able to get one draggable text but i want the user to add multiple text . can you please help me out .

I am fetching the image via my api and i have created a stacked layout on which i have added my text .
I have provided some text customization option to users . I want users to add multiple text and they can also customize them

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:math';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:admob_flutter/admob_flutter.dart';
import 'package:bordered_text/bordered_text.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:flutter_colorpicker/flutter_colorpicker.dart';
import 'package:image_gallery_saver/image_gallery_saver.dart';
import 'package:meme_app/Screens/CustomMemes.dart';
import 'package:meme_app/Services/admob_services.dart';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'package:meme_app/image editor/lists.dart';

import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

class CustomSceen3 extends StatefulWidget {

  final String imgUrl;
  final File imgFile;
  CustomSceen3({
    this.imgUrl,
    this.imgFile,
  });
  @override
  _CustomSceen3State createState() => _CustomSceen3State();
}



class _CustomSceen3State extends State<CustomSceen3> {

 

  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> scaffoldState = GlobalKey();

 

 


  Size size = Size(600, 800);
  List<Widget> data = <Widget>[];
  Offset offset = Offset.zero;




  String addedText = '';
  String newText;
  int total=0;

  //settings
  Color pickerColor = Color(0xffffffff);
  Color currentColor = Color(0xffffffff);

  double textSize = 28.0;
  String customFont = 'Aileron-Black';
  GlobalKey _key = GlobalKey();
  File _imageFile;
  Random rng = new Random();
  int whiteSpace = 0;


  bool strike = false;
  double strokeSize = 2.0;
  Color strokePickerColor = Color(0xff000000);
  Color strokeCurrentColor = Color(0xff000000);


  TextEditingController myController = TextEditingController()
    ..text = "";


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  child: Center(
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: Container(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        child: RepaintBoundary(
                          key: _key,
                          child: Stack(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Column(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Container(
                                    height: whiteSpace.toDouble() * 5,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                  ),
                                  widget.imgFile == null
                                      ? Image(
                                    image: NetworkImage(widget.imgUrl),
                                  )
                                      : Image.file(widget.imgFile, height: 300,
                                    width: MediaQuery
                                        .of(context)
                                        .size
                                        .width,
                                    fit: BoxFit.fill,),
                                ],
                              ),
                              Positioned(
                                left: offset.dx,
                                top: offset.dy,
                                child: GestureDetector(
                                  onPanUpdate: (details) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      offset = Offset(
                                          offset.dx + details.delta.dx, offset.dy + details.delta.dy);
                                    });
                                  },
                                  child: Container(
                                    child: BorderedText(
                                      strokeColor: strokeCurrentColor,
                                      strokeWidth:  strokeSize ,
                                      child: Text(
                                        addedText,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontFamily: customFont,
                                            fontSize: textSize,
                                            color: currentColor
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),

                            ],
                          ),
                        ),

                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
            ),

            Container(
                color: Colors.black,
                height: 80.0,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: [
                          DropdownButton<int>(
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                            value: whiteSpace,
                            dropdownColor: Colors.black87,
                            isDense: true,
                            icon: Icon(Icons.padding, color: Colors.white,),
                            iconSize: 30,
                            onChanged: (int newValue) {
                              setState(() {
                                whiteSpace = newValue;
                              });
                            },
                            items: whiteSpaceList
                                .map<DropdownMenuItem<int>>((int value) {
                              return DropdownMenuItem<int>(
                                value: value,
                                child: Text(value.toString() + "%"),
                              );
                            }).toList(),
                          ),
                          Center(
                            child: Text(
                              "Add Space", maxLines: 2, overflow: TextOverflow
                                .clip,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 11, color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: [
                          IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(Icons.text_format, color: Colors.white,
                                size: 30,),
                              onPressed: ()  {
                                TextDialog();
                              }
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "Text", maxLines: 2, overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 11, color: Colors.white),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: [
                          IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(
                                Icons.emoji_emotions_outlined, color: Colors
                                  .white, size: 30,),
                              onPressed: null
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "Sticker", maxLines: 2, overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 11, color: Colors.white),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: [
                          IconButton(
                              icon: Icon(Icons.download_outlined, color: Colors
                                  .white, size: 30,),
                              onPressed: null
                          ),
                          Text(
                            "Save", maxLines: 2, overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 11, color: Colors.white),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: (){
                          setTextStyle();
                        },
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              "Aa",style:TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 30,color: Colors.white,fontFamily: 'ComicRelief'
                            ),
                            ),
                            Text(
                              "Font", maxLines: 2, overflow: TextOverflow.clip,
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 11, color: Colors.white),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                )
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


 
  Widget setTextStyle(){
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context){
          return Dialog(
            backgroundColor: Colors.black54,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
              child: SizedBox(
                height: 400,
                child: Center(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      CustomTextStyle(
                        tittle: "Black Text",
                        color: Colors.white,
                        strokecolor: Colors.white,
                        font: 'OpenSans-Regular',
                        strokewidth: 0.0,
                        onTap: (){
                          setState(() {
                            strokeSize= 0.0;
                            currentColor=Colors.black;
                            customFont= 'OpenSans-Regular';
                            strokeCurrentColor=Colors.white;
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();

                          });
                        },
                      ),
                      CustomTextStyle(
                        tittle: "STANDARD MEME",
                        color: Colors.white,
                        strokecolor: Colors.black,
                        font: 'Anton',
                        strokewidth: 3.0,
                        onTap: (){
                          setState(() {
                            strokeSize= 3.0;
                            currentColor=Colors.white;
                            customFont= 'Anton';
                            strokeCurrentColor=Colors.black;
                            addedText=addedText.toUpperCase();
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();

                          });
                        },
                      ),
                      CustomTextStyle(
                        tittle: "Modern Meme",
                        color: Colors.black,
                        strokecolor: Colors.white,
                        font: 'OpenSans-Regular',
                        strokewidth: 3.0,
                        onTap: (){
                          setState(() {
                            strokeSize= 3.0;
                            currentColor=Colors.black;
                            customFont= 'OpenSans-Regular';
                            strokeCurrentColor=Colors.white;
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();

                          });
                        },
                      ),
                      CustomTextStyle(
                        tittle: "Dark Modern Meme",
                        color: Colors.white,
                        strokecolor: Colors.black,
                        font: 'OpenSans-Regular',
                        strokewidth: 3.0,
                        onTap: (){
                          setState(() {
                            strokeSize= 3.0;
                            currentColor=Colors.white;
                            customFont= 'OpenSans-Regular';
                            strokeCurrentColor=Colors.black;
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();

                          });
                        },
                      ),
                      CustomTextStyle(
                        tittle: "Black Object White Outline",
                        color: Colors.black,
                        strokecolor: Colors.white,
                        font: 'Aileron-Bold',
                        strokewidth: 3.0,
                        onTap: (){
                          setState(() {
                            strokeSize= 3.0;
                            currentColor=Colors.black;
                            customFont= 'Aileron-Bold';
                            strokeCurrentColor=Colors.white;
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();

                          });
                        },
                      ),
                      CustomTextStyle(
                        tittle: "White Object Black Outline",
                        color: Colors.white,
                        strokecolor: Colors.black,
                        font: 'Aileron-Bold',
                        strokewidth: 3.0,
                        onTap: (){
                          setState(() {
                            strokeSize= 3.0;
                            currentColor=Colors.white;
                            customFont= 'OpenSans-Regular';
                            strokeCurrentColor=Colors.black;
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                      CustomTextStyle(
                        tittle: "Yellow Subtittle",
                        color: Color(0xfeFFE400),
                        strokecolor: Colors.black,
                        font: 'OpenSans-Regular',
                        strokewidth: 3.0,
                        onTap: (){
                          setState(() {
                            strokeSize= 3.0;
                            currentColor=Color(0xfeFFE400);
                            customFont= 'OpenSans-Regular';
                            strokeCurrentColor=Colors.black;
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                          });
                        },
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
    );
  }

  Widget TextDialog() {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        barrierDismissible: true, // user must tap button!
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return ListView(

            children:[ Container(color: Colors.black54,
              child: Dialog(
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: [
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              IconButton(
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.invert_colors, color: Colors.white),
                                  onPressed: null),
                              IconButton(
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.add_circle, color: Colors.white),
                                  onPressed: null),
                              IconButton(
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.remove_circle, color: Colors.white),
                                  onPressed: null),
                              IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.format_align_center_outlined), onPressed: null)
                            ],
                          ),
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                            children: [
                              OutlineButton(
                                borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1.0,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    style: BorderStyle.solid),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    
                                    addedText = myController.text;
                                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                  }
                                  );
                                },
                                child: Text(
                                  "Got it", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      textfield(),
                      Container(height: 50,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        child: ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: colors.length,
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal, physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                              child: GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    currentColor = colors[index];
                                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                    TextDialog();
                                  });
                                },
                                child: Container(
                                  width: 40.0,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color: colors[index], //this is the important line
                                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                      border: Border.all(
                                          width: 2.0, color: Colors.white60)
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            ],
          );

        }
    );
  }






  Widget textfield() {
    return TextField(
      controller: myController,
      maxLines: 10,
    );

  }

}



class CustomTextStyle extends StatelessWidget {

  CustomTextStyle({this.color,this.tittle,this.strokecolor,this.font,this.strokewidth,this.onTap
  });

  final Color color;
  final Color strokecolor;
  final double strokewidth;
  final String tittle;
  final String font;
  final Function onTap;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      onTap: onTap,
      title: BorderedText(
        strokeColor: strokecolor,
        strokeWidth: strokewidth,
        child: Text(
          tittle,
          style: TextStyle(
              color: color,fontFamily: font,fontSize: 17,letterSpacing: 1.05
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is your code? What have you tried to solve your problem? Have you taken a look at this: https://medium.com/flutter-community/a-deep-dive-into-draggable-and-dragtarget-in-flutter-487919f6f1e4

Comment: i have added my code snippet can you please take a look at it

Comment: You dumped your entire code and you're making me add multiple text and allow them to be customized :(  Stackoverflow is a place where people help you with bugs and problems in your code and it is not a coding service. What have you tried to solve your problem? Have you looked at the article above?